# Send SMS program from Oracle Applications completing in Error

Tags: java, oracle

There is an error while sending SMS to users through the concurrent program Send Subinventory SMS.

The message is constructed and a host program is internally launched From PL/SQL Procedure

This program calls jSMS.jar from the path /opt/oraappl/x/apps/apps_st/appl/xxdev/1.0/bin. This part of java is erroring out with the follwoing java exception.

```
Sending SMS .....
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassFormatError: java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder  (erroneous method access flags)
at _Jv_ClassReader.throw_class_format_error(byte) (/usr/lib64/libgcj.so.5.0.0)
at _Jv_ClassReader.handleMethod(int, int, int, int) (/usr/lib64/libgcj.so.5.0.0)
at _Jv_ClassReader.read_methods() (/usr/lib64/libgcj.so.5.0.0)
at _Jv_ClassReader.parse() (/usr/lib64/libgcj.so.5.0.0)
at _Jv_DefineClass(java.lang.Class, byte[], int, int) (/usr/lib64/libgcj.so.5.0.0)
at java.lang.VMClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.ClassLoader, java.lang.String, byte[],  int, int, java.security.ProtectionDomain) (/usr/lib64/libgcj.so.5.0.0)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String, byte[], int, int, java.security.ProtectionDomain) (/usr/lib64/libgcj.so.5.0.0)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String, byte[], int, int, java.security.CodeSource) (/usr/lib64/libgcj.so.5.0.0)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (/usr/lib64/libgcj.so.5.0.0)
at gnu.gcj.runtime.VMClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (/usr/lib64/libgcj.so.5.0.0)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (/usr/lib64/libgcj.so.5.0.0)
at _Jv_FindClass(_Jv_Utf8Const, java.lang.ClassLoader) (/usr/lib64/libgcj.so.5.0.0)
at _Jv_ClassReader.handleClassBegin(int, int, int) (/usr/lib64/libgcj.so.5.0.0)
at _Jv_ClassReader.parse() (/usr/lib64/libgcj.so.5.0.0)
at _Jv_DefineClass(java.lang.Class, byte[], int, int) (/usr/lib64/libgcj.so.5.0.0)
at java.lang.VMClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.ClassLoader, java.lang.String, byte[], int, int, java.security.ProtectionDomain) (/usr/lib64/libgcj.so.5.0.0)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String, byte[], int, int, java.security.ProtectionDomain) (/usr/lib64/libgcj.so.5.0.0)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String, byte[], int, int, java.security.CodeSource) (/usr/lib64/libgcj.so.5.0.0)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (/usr/lib64/libgcj.so.5.0.0)
at gnu.gcj.runtime.VMClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (/usr/lib64/libgcj.so.5.0.0)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (/usr/lib64/libgcj.so.5.0.0)
at _Jv_FindClass(_Jv_Utf8Const, java.lang.ClassLoader) (/usr/lib64/libgcj.so.5.0.0)
at java.lang.Class.forName(java.lang.String, boolean, java.lang.ClassLoader) (/usr/lib64/libgcj.so.5.0.0)
at _Jv_BytecodeVerifier.verify_instructions_0() (/usr/lib64/libgcj.so.5.0.0)
at _Jv_VerifyMethod(_Jv_InterpMethod) (/usr/lib64/libgcj.so.5.0.0)
at _Jv_PrepareClass(java.lang.Class) (/usr/lib64/libgcj.so.5.0.0)
at _Jv_WaitForState(java.lang.Class, int) (/usr/lib64/libgcj.so.5.0.0)
at java.lang.VMClassLoader.linkClass0(java.lang.Class) (/usr/lib64/libgcj.so.5.0.0)
at java.lang.VMClassLoader.resolveClass(java.lang.Class) (/usr/lib64/libgcj.so.5.0.0)
at java.lang.Class.initializeClass() (/usr/lib64/libgcj.so.5.0.0)
at java.lang.Class.forName(java.lang.String, boolean, java.lang.ClassLoader) (/usr/lib64/libgcj.so.5.0.0)
at gnu.gcj.runtime.FirstThread.run() (/usr/lib64/libgcj.so.5.0.0)
at _Jv_ThreadRun(java.lang.Thread) (/usr/lib64/libgcj.so.5.0.0)
at _Jv_RunMain(java.lang.Class, byte const, int, byte const, boolean) (/usr/lib64/libgcj.so.5.0.0)
at __gcj_personality_v0 (/opt/oraappl/x/inst/apps/x_tham/logs/appl/conc/log/java.version=1.4.2)
at __libc_start_main (/lib64/tls/libc-2.3.4.so)
at _Jv_RegisterClasses  (/opt/oraappl/x/inst/apps/x_tham/logs/appl/conc/log/java.version=1.4.2)
/opt/oraappl/x/apps/apps_st/appl/xxdev/1.0/bin/XXDEV_SEND_SMS
Program exited with status 1
```

Comment: Maybe an incompatibility between gcj and Oracle's Java?

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your valuable answer. But can you please elaborate further. java version "1.4.2"
gcj (GCC) 3.4.6 20060404 (Red Hat 3.4.6-11)

Comment: Try compiling your java classes with Oracle's javac (not gcj) and make sure that the Oracle RDBMS finds Oracle's java in its path, not gcj.